# How to find and click on a button in page by name using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to find and click a button in a page by name or text.
HTML:

```
<input name="ppw-widgetEvent:SetPaymentPlanSelectContinueEvent" class="a-button-input a-button-text" type="submit" aria-labelledby="pp-NKOnMC-86-announce">
```

Code trials:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "name']"))).click()
```

PS: I think the element is dynamic, and in page stay 2 button with same function e name, therefore I can't use element by name.

Comment: Finding an element by name requires that an element has a name attribute, e.g., `<input type="button" name="foo">`.

Comment: the button is this:

Comment: <input name="ppw-widgetEvent:SetPaymentPlanSelectContinueEvent" class="a-button-input a-button-text" type="submit" aria-labelledby="pp-NKOnMC-86-announce">

Comment: i think is dynamic, and in page stay 2 button with same function e name, therefore i can't use element by name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there are 2 buttons with the same `name` attribute on the page you need to club up some of the unique attribute while constructing the locator which will identify the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) uniquely within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

---

### Solution

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.a-button-input.a-button-text[name='ppw-widgetEvent:SetPaymentPlanSelectContinueEvent'][aria-labelledby$='announce']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='a-button-input a-button-text' and @name='ppw-widgetEvent:SetPaymentPlanSelectContinueEvent'][contains(@aria-labelledby, 'announce')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```